# issue on adding to dxDatagrid

Tags: jquery, html, devextreme

I am using dxDataGrid devextreme(jquery).
I have a master-detaile grid that its shows countries and city list of each country.
when I add a country its work. but when I click to add button cities I got an error in a console that I can not add.

where is my problem?

```
$(function () {
    $("#gridCountry").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: {
            store: {
                type: "array",
                key: "ID",
                data: countries
            }
        },
        columns: [{
            dataField: "CountryLatinName",
            caption: "Country Name(Latin)"
        }],
        editing: {
            mode: "form",
            allowUpdating: true,
            allowDeleting: true,
            allowAdding: true
        },
        masterDetail: {
            enabled: true,
            template: function (container, options) {
                var country = options.data;
                container.addClass("internal-grid-container");
                $("<div>").text(country.CountryLatinName).appendTo(container);
                $("<div>")
                    .addClass("internal-grid")
                    .dxDataGrid({
                        editing: {
                            mode: "form",
                            allowUpdating: true,
                            allowDeleting: true,
                            allowAdding: true
                        },
                        columnAutoWidth: true,
                        columns: [{
                            dataField: "CityLatinName",
                            caption:"City Name(Latin)"
                        }, {
                            dataField: "GMT",
                            dataType:"number"
                        }, {
                            dataField:"Capital",
                            dataType: "boolean"
                        }],
                        dataSource: country.Cities
                    }).appendTo(container);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

this is my error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and this is array of countries :

```
var countries = [{
    "ID": 3,
    "CountryLatinName": "Turkey",
    "PhonePrefixes":"+90",
    "Cities": [{
        "ID": 30,
        "CityLatinName": "Ankara",
        "GMT": "+3:00",
        "Capital": true
    }, {
        "ID": 31,
        "CityLatinName": "Istanbul",
        "GMT": "+3:00",
        "Capital": false
    }, {
        "ID": 32,
        "CityLatinName": "Bodrum",
        "GMT": "+3:00",
        "Capital": false
    }, {
        "ID": 33,
        "CityLatinName": "Izmir",
        "GMT": "+3:00",
        "Capital": false
    }]
}];
```

Comment: What exactly error did you get? And could you provide a piece of the `countries` array?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3ykswncc/3/

Answer (score 1):

When you are creating a new country the `Cities` array is missing. Well, you can fix it using the [rowInserting](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/16_2/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDataGrid/Events/#rowInserting) event:

```
onRowInserting: function(e) {
    e.data.Cities = [];
}
```

The example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hkqj2c6s/).